# Ошибка при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

```
Паршу olx через bs4,выдает ошибку.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url='https://www.olx.ua/obyavlenie/iphone-6-IDHPtbm.html#eee3b8ca1b'
def req(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    return r.text
def bs4(html):
    soup=(html,'html.parser')
    tovarName = soup.find('div', {'class': 'offer-titlebox'}).find('h1').text
    return tovarName



def main():
    req(url)
    print(bs4(req(url)))
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Ошибка: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Посмотрите, что возвращает метод find у soup

Comment: Что он возвращает

Comment: Объект find не имеет атрибута find. Читайте гайд по парсингу:
https://python-scripts.com/beautifulsoup-html-parsing